# Python pigpio 'no permission to update GPIO'

Tags: gpio, python, pigpio, permissions

I am trying to run the following code on my Raspberry:

```
import pigpio 
import fileinput

pi = pigpio.pi()

### Define constants 
pwm_range = 255 
pwm_clock_div = 8 

left_motor_dir_pin = 35 
left_motor_pwm_pin = 32 

right_motor_dir_pin = 31 
right_motor_pwm_pin = 33 

left_motor_current_pin = 37
right_motor_current_pin = 29 

for pin in [left_motor_dir_pin, right_motor_dir_pin, left_motor_pwm_pin, right_motor_pwm_pin]:
    pi.set_mode(pin,pigpio.OUTPUT)
```

However this sends the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gpio-test.py", line 20, in <module>
    pi.set_mode(pin,pigpio.OUTPUT)
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pigpio.py", line 1296, in set_mode
    return _u2i(_pigpio_command(self.sl, _PI_CMD_MODES, gpio, mode))
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pigpio.py", line 970, in _u2i
    raise error(error_text(v))
pigpio.error: 'no permission to update GPIO'
```

I started `pigpiod` with `sudo pigpiod`, it sends the same error with `sudo`.

Any idea why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pigpio only uses Broadcom numbering for the GPIO.

You do not mention which Pi you are using but recent Pi's have 28 accessible GPIO numbered 0 to 27.

You appear to be using pin numbering.

You need to change the pin numbers to GPIO numbers.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html#Type_3

https://pinout.xyz/

Answer (score 0):

In order for user pi to be able to access gpios without root permissions on a michine with the device tree disabled, udev rules are needed for both `/sys/class/gpio and /sys/devices/virtual/gpio`. They are needed for `/sys/devices/virtual/gpio` because the gpioN directories in `/sys/class/gpio` are links to the gpioN directories in `/sys/devices/virtual/gpio`. 
For example, see directory gpio4 here:

```
pi@raspberrypi /sys/class/gpio $ echo 4 > export 
pi@raspberrypi /sys/class/gpio $ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwx---  2 root gpio    0 Feb  7 20:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 38 root root    0 Feb  7 19:28 ..
-rwxrwx---  1 root gpio 4096 Feb  7 20:11 export
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root gpio    0 Feb  7 20:11 gpio4 -> ../../devices/virtual/gpio/gpio4
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root gpio    0 Jan  1  1970 gpiochip0 -> ../../devices/virtual/gpio/gpiochip0
-rwxrwx---  1 root gpio 4096 Feb  7 19:40 unexport
pi@raspberrypi /sys/class/gpio $
```

I can't think of a same reason to use `/sys/devices/virtual/gpio` in source code as `/sys/class/gpio` can always be used instead, if I'm not mistaken.

Note that this only functions when the device tree is disabled. When the device tree is enabled, `/sys/devices/virtual/gpio` disappears.

If the device tree is enabled, the udev rules on the Pi 2 need to use `/sys/devices/soc/3f200000.gpio/gpio/` instead. The address 3f200000 may be different on the Pi 1, I'm not sure.

Note that `/sys/devices/virtual/gpio` is used in both /lib/udev/rules.d/60-python3-pifacecommon.rules and /lib/udev/rules.d/60-python-pifacecommon.rules in Raspbian. I've no idea how many users rely on this now.

Comment: Thanks, in my case it didn't work even with sudo, the answer above fixed it !